# iOS Login process works on simulator but not iPhone (3GS)

Tags: ios, core-data, keychain

I created a login process for an iPhone app I am developing, and the login process works in the iOS Simulator app in Xcode, but doesn't work on my actual phone.  The code for the login process is:

```
- (IBAction)processLogin:(id)sender {

// hide keyboard
[_textFieldUsername resignFirstResponder];
[_textFieldPin resignFirstResponder];


// First - make activity indicator visible, then start animating, then turn of wrong user / pin label
_welcomeActivityIndicator.hidden = FALSE;
[_welcomeActivityIndicator startAnimating];
[_wrongUserPin setHidden:YES];

// check if username and pin text fields are populated
if ([_textFieldUsername.text length ] == 0 &&  [_textFieldPin.text length ] == 0)
{
    [_welcomeActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [_wrongUserPin setHidden:NO];   
}

// CORE DATA
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

// set entity for request
[request setEntity:entity];

// filter results using a predicate
NSPredicate *pred =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:(@"username = %@"), _textFieldUsername.text];

// set predicate for the request
[request setPredicate:pred];

NSError *error = nil;

// store DB usernames in results array
NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSLog(@"The returned results are %@",results);


// check text field against results stored in DB
for (Account *anAccount in results) {
    if ([anAccount.username isEqualToString:_textFieldUsername.text]){
        NSLog(@"Your username exists");
        if ([anAccount.password isEqualToString:_textFieldPin.text]){
            NSLog(@"Your pin is correct");

            // TODO - put this in proper place - play audio bell if user logs in correctly
            CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
            CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
            soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Glass", CFSTR("aiff"), NULL);
            UInt32 soundID;
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

            // TODO - put this in proper place - Load ViewController(Root)Home
            if([anAccount.username isEqualToString:@"root"])
            {
                UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
                ViewControllerRootHome *roothome = (ViewControllerRootHome *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rootHome"];
                [self presentModalViewController:roothome animated:YES];
            }
            else {
                UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
                ViewControllerHome *home = (ViewControllerHome *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
                [self presentModalViewController:home animated:YES];
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Your pin is wrong");
            [_welcomeActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
            [_wrongUserPin setHidden:NO];
            }
        }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Your username was not found");
        [_welcomeActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [_wrongUserPin setHidden:NO];
        }
    }

}
```

I am storing the username in a Core Data DB, and storing the pin in the keychain.  I am able to create an account on the iPhone, and the info scene shows that there are created accounts on the iPhone, but when I try to login all I see is *Username or pin is wrong*

The project can be downloaded from here https://github.com/ipatch/KegCop/zipball/master

Comment: I tried deleting the app and building and running the app again on the phone but I am still experiencing the same results.

Comment: What does it mean 'doesn't work' what DOES it do?

Comment: @Lablabla "but when I try to login all I see is Username or pin is wrong" the user isn't taken to the home scene rather welcome scene stays on the screen, thus the user never logs in.

Comment: Sorry. missed that part.
I can't find this NSLog outputing this. is that the console output?

Comment: You need to give us a copy of your NSLog output.  Also, try logging the textfields + anAccount.username and anAccount.password to make sure the expected content matches the inputs

Comment: @RoboticCat is it possible to have the Logs from the app running on the phone display in the "Debug Area" of Xcode?


Right now when I click "run" from within Xcode the app launches on my phone then quits / goes back to the home screen.  In the output area of the "Debug Area" I get the following error,

"error: failed to launch '/Users/.../Xcode/DreviedData/KegCop-.../Build/Products/Debug/-iphoneos/KegCop.app/KegCop' -- failed to get the task for process 547

If it makes a difference my iPhone is jailbroken, and I am using AppSync to get my app to run on the iPhone.

Comment: Yes it makes a difference. You can't debug (at least I didn't find a way) on a jailbroken iPhone without the apple certification which u can obtain when signing for the 99$/year program. so no. no way that I know of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what solved this problem, but after completing the [following tutorial](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/developing-jailbroken-iphone-ios-401/), the login process was working again.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are storing a username/password to CoreData anywhere in this code. Are you sure your default DB has entries in it?

Comment: I'm not trying to store data to core data but rather check if the username tf matches a username stored in the Core Data DB, and if the pin tf equals the pin stored in the keychain.  This is the login process, not the account creation process.  The accounts are being created, the users can't login for whatever reason (o.O)

Comment: I understand that, but at this point, have you ensured the DB actually has the entries you think they do?

Comment: Well in the "About" scene it says there are created accounts on the system.  You can download the project I am working on at https://github.com/ipatch/KegCop/zipball/master and see that the code works in the simulator, but when you test on your phone let me know the results you get.

Comment: I won't install it, but you can add the code to the original question so others can try if they want to.